# LEDs, Reverse Polarity, and Battery Life

Tags: led

Would an LED hooked up to a coin cell battery (3v) in reverse, cause any issues with the lifespan of the battery or the LED?  The LED would be acting as a photoresistor, supplying somewhere in the neighborhood of +0.2v back to the non-rechargeable battery in direct sunlight.  Could I expect a reduction in the lifespan of the LED, which seems unlikely, or a reduction in the charge of the battery over time?

Comment: Just to see what woudl happen, I gave this a brief test on a "rainbow" LED which cycles between RGB via an integrated IC.  There is only a single pair of anode/cathode connections, with all the circuitry residing inside the LED.  After 60 minutes, the LED appeared to not be functional at all.  Over the next 5-10 minutes, each color began to appear dimly, with red first, followed by blue, and ending with green.  Each color appears to be at full brightness now.  Very strange.  For curiosity's sake, I'll have to try this again with a plain LED to see what the negative impact is.

Comment: what you telling is not clear. Can you come up with a diagram ?

Comment: The IC is integrated into the LED, so it's just 1 led, 1 3v coin cell battery.  I realize this isn't the same as hooking up a standard led, just some interesting behavior I obvserved.

edit: ascii schematics don't work well on SE.

Comment: As a practical example: Let's say you have a single led keychain style flashlight with no switch.  Would simply reversing the battery, (rather than disconnecting) be a valid means of shutting off the flashlight, or could one expect negative effects on the LED or Battery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is that it is safe, and all single LED's use a -5V Vr max spec.

But for leakage, there may be exceptions beyond your requirements due to wounded LED's that leak more than spec, from overstress due to static discharge, solder temperature, operating temperature, moisture ingress and others, which all affect leakage.  Also increased chip sizes from 0.1W to 1W to 10W will undoubtedly leak more from total area, but vary from OEM to OEM on specs.  I can't speak for all Chinese factories of flashlights to see if they buy LED's that are guaranteed low leakage, 1vs 10 vs 100uA but low leakage is a quality factor to consider qualifying a source of LED's in large volume for reliability reasons. As aging factors, contamination, moisture ingress all affect leakage as well as ESD/EOS.

Using a 1MOhm series resistor you can create a curve-tracer using a scope, signal gen. and xy mode and compare LED leakage specs, if you have a batch and verify as I have done on a sample basis. Solder temp over stress can also affect leakage.

In the end your lithium coin cell leakage when cold may be good for 10 years and when hot maybe only a few years. The reverse connection idea may be adquate, but the flashlight designs I have seen all include a screw cap threaded switch contact or momentary if it is a multi-function flashlight, then use a momentary switch. Then they use a plastic ABS shim in series with the battery with a pull-away tab or removal instructions for shipment to avoid power activation during shipment.